# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError, Tried the research fixes... A migrating gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, connection, timeout

Update: now back to migration pending error.. Can i just delete the gem... Cant seem to get that to work either...
Keep getting this error.
Tried to install a gem and have continued to have issues ever sense....it was syntax now this.  I have been at it for hours with little luck .  It is coming up in my port from rails.... Trying to look at my app.  I am new to this... so probably shouldn't have ventured off into the unknown like that... Ran rake middleware

`ActionDispatch::Callbacks
 use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
 use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
 use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
 use ActionDispatch::Cookies
 use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
 use ActionDispatch::Flash
 use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
 use Rack::Head
 use Rack::ConditionalGet`

It has something to do with migration.i tried every little fix i could find dealing with migration pending problem. I just want what I had back up!  I am in the one month rails class and got a little bold :)!

Comment: Which gem were you trying to install?

Comment: fixed after a day by running brew install postgres --no-ossp-uuid, that was the problem.

Comment: Thanks! postgres in home brew apparently has this issue a good bit.... found the answer on github for future newbies... I guess you can find the answer here!  LEARNING BY DOING! type command brew install postgre s --no-ossp-uuid